# Will this particular use of an anonymous Runnable cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, memory-leaks

```
private class ProductFragment extends Fragment implements OnGetProductFromDBListener {

    Activity a;

    void onCreate {
         a = getActivity();
        new GetProductFromDB();
    }


    void onGetProductSuccess(Product product) { // This is not called from the main thread because of the implementation of GetProductFromDB
        a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            void run() {
                // do some UI and Views related stuff
            }

        });
    } 

}
```

Now, the Runnable being an anonymous class should hold an explicit reference to the Fragment, right? And this would prevent the Fragment from being Garbage Collected?

Should I worry about a memory leak occurring and how should I prevent it?

Will it help if I instantiate a class that extends Runnable and make it static?

```
private static class RunnableTask extends Runnable {


  ProductFragment fragment;

   public RunnableTask (ProductFragment fragment) {
       this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    void run() {

       if(fragment.someBoolean) {
           fragment.doSomething();
       }

    }
}

RunnableTask runnable = new RunnableTask();
a.runOnUiThread(runnable)
```

Comment: the reference is hold as long as the run is under execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it won't necessarily result in a memory leak. BUT - for the duration of the thread's run it will hold a reference to the outer class (ProductFragment in your case). So whether it's a memory leak will depend on how long the thread will run for, and whether it ends up being the only reference left to the ProductFragment class.

Your suggestion of breaking it out into a static inner class is a good one as this will remove that reference to the outer class and hence remove any chance of the potential memory  leak.

HOWEVER - In your case, seeing as your proposed static class holds on to a reference of the outer class instance anyway, there is no benefit from doing this.

Comment: so instead of trying to guess how long will the run method take, I can just do some prevention and break it out, right? just to be on the safe side

Comment: Now I need to access the fragment's viariables, from within that class. In this case I pass the fragment to the constructor of that class, right?

Comment: Exactly. I'm pretty sure the book Effective Java (highly recommended) recommends using static inner class whenever possible for exactly this sort of reason. I'd recommend taking a look if you want more detail.

Comment: Ah... That changes things... If you need to access stuff inside ProgramFragment then you might as well leave it as it is as you'll be holding onto the reference anyway. You'd only use the static if the thread didn't need to do that.

Comment: Are you sure? Once another person told me that it was safe to pass the fragment in the constructor of a static inner class, so that I avoid memory leaks

Comment: The other person is right, it's fine to do it. But if you then hold on to the outer class instance (by putting it into a field say) then you effectively have the same result - the thread will hold on to the reference until it is completed. So you've added code that gives you no benefit. If on the other hand you pass the outer class instance to the constructor but don't hold on to it outside the constructor, then yes... You should do that instead.

Comment: I've edited my question to show you what Im doing, just in case. So, now that you can see what Im actually doing, you can confirm that this is redundant, and I should just leave it an anonymous class?

Comment: Correct. Leave the anonymous class. I've edited my answer accordingly.